# Offline demo on Android tablet with no microSD?

Tags: android

Can I store web pages on an Android device that lacks a microSD slot, so I can deliver an offline demo?

I asked a similar question a little while ago, but I assumed the device I was thinking of buying HAD a microSD slot -- but now I'm afraid it might not. The device in question is the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, due out next week. Earlier demo models had a microSD slot, but although the specs are not entirely clear, it looks like the production version might not. If it lacks a microSD slot, will I somehow be able to save the demo in internal memory, or will I be out of luck?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Questions related to how devices use its storage may be more on topic in android.stackexchange.com. That is, unless you're question is about how to use `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Typically there is a storage space on the device, however it is not really usable. When you plug the device into a computer you are actually storing and accessing files on the sdcard. However if this device does not have an sdcard then there is a high chance that it would allow you to store files on the internal flash storage. You could then access these files to give a demo just like if you had an sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new Galaxy Tab 10.1 comes with between 16 and 32gb of internal flash memory. Though failing to include a MicroSD slot in the first place is unusual, it's highly unlikely that they won't allow you to use some of that 16+GB for your own files. That would mean you'd be unable to copy MP3s to the device via USB, for example, which would annoy a lot of people.

Part or all of the 16+GB should be partitioned and made available for your use.

Comment: Traditionally devices without an sdcard slot have basically had a "soldered in" sdcard equivalent with a FAT filesystem on it.  In Honeycomb that's apparently done away with and the user storage is integrated with the rest of the non-factory data, no longer being a separate partition.  I would be very surprised if this device does not have a USB port; more likely this is a confused reference to it not allowing mounting the user storage as a USB mass storage device, because Honeycomb uses the MTP protocol to provide shared access to the storage rather the USB mass storage protocol.

Comment: Yeah, a review said it had no USB ports, but the specs say it comes with a USB cable. I assume the reviewer meant it has no *standard* Mini-USB port.